# Ember.js with Rails4: browser back button crash ember application

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks, ember-rails

EDIT: the issue is solved. Removing **turbolinks** is all you need to do.

With a **Rails4** application the use **ember-rails 0.13.0** we have a problem of not functional browser back button. Each time while getting back to previous route using the back button the application is crashing with such errors:

on Firefox 24.0a2:

```
TypeError: Class.PrototypeMixin.applyPartial is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:11933
```

on Chromium 28:

```
Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded! jquery.js?body=1:517I 
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.6.1 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.2 ember.js?body=1:364
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

It looks like the whole application stack is loaded again that ends with not functional code base. Anyway the same application works perfectly good with **Rails3**.

Reports from other people having problems with **ember.js** together with **turbolinks**:

```
Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some debugging we had noticed those are **turbolinks** causing the problem. Using backbutton triggered **turbolinks** which were causing strange effects with the ember.js application like reloading all javascripts and thus overriding the state of app.

Removing **turbolinks** done the job. Here is a useful link how to do it: http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

Comment: Turbolinks also causes "Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM" errors in Ember - again, went away when I kicked Turbolinks to the curb.

Comment: @Nathan thanks for report. I've attached it to original question as it may help someone.