# Ember throwing error when hitting the browser's back and forward buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-rails

I have the following routes:

```
Redb.Router.map ()->
  @resource "forms", ->
    @route "new"
    @route  "show", path: "/:form_id"
```

I have associated templates and controllers.

Using links generated by `link-to` helper, everything works fine, but, for example when I am `#/forms/1` and hit back to go to `#/forms` it gives these errors:

```
Assertion failed: The initializer 'store' has already been registered
Assertion failed: The initializer 'dataAdapter' has already been registered
Assertion failed: The initializer 'injectStore' has already been registered
```

And then, when I hit forward button I get:

```
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2726:19)
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.find (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:1730:17)
    at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.findModel (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:34817:23)
    at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.model (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:34806:17)
    at getModel (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:33269:45)
    at model (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:33197:17)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9428:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9098:9)
    at Promise.publishFulfillment (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9518:7)
    at Object.DeferredActionQueues.flush (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:5651:24)

Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:2726:19)
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.find (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember-data.js?body=1:1730:17)
    at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.findModel (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:34817:23)
    at Ember.Route.Ember.Object.extend.model (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:34806:17)
    at getModel (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:33269:45)
    at model (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:33197:17)
    at invokeCallback (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9428:19)
    at publish (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9098:9)
    at Promise.publishFulfillment (http://localhost:3000/assets/ember.js?body=1:9518:7)
```

I am new to Ember and I am trying to learn it. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142401/ember-js-with-rails4-browser-back-button-crash-ember-application), the problem is with `turbolinks`, when back and forward buttons are clicked `turbolinks` causes strange effects.

Removing `turbolinks` solves the problem.