# Rails javascript assets behaving oddly depending on routing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm currently learning Rails, and I'm wanting to use angular in my project.

Here's a simple application from scratch.

1). Create a new rails app:

```
rails new hello_rails
```

2). Add angular gem to **Gemfile**

```
gem 'angularjs-rails'
```

3). Install the bundle

```
bundle install
```

4). Add angular to javascript manifest in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//=require angular
```

5). Generate welcome index

```
rails generate controller welcome index
```

6). Populate index.html.erb with an angular hello world

```
 <div style = "background-color: grey">
    this is index.html.erb<br>

  <div ng-app="">
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>

</div>
```

7). Also modify application.html.erb

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HelloRails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body style = "background-color:green">

  This is application.html.erb <br>

   <%= link_to "click here to go home", root_path %> <br>

A yeild statement is below: <br>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

8). Set root route to `welcome#index` in `config/routes.rb`

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Run this - this works fine.

Here's what we get:

[image]

The angular is working:

[image]

However, if I click the link to return to `root_path` it stops working

[image]

Additionally, if we add some angular to our `application.html.erb` the yielded angular stops working.

```
<div ng-app="">
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="home_name"></p>
<h1>Hello {{home_name}} at home</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Can you explain why rails is working this way?

Comment: Have you removed turbolinks?

Comment: I don't think turbolinks and angular are meant to be used together and will most likely not play nice. Remove turbolinks from your Gemfile and `//= require turbolinks` from your `application.js`.

Comment: @max - Thanks, that solves the first issue (where it stops working if you click the link to return home), but you still have the issue where the yeilded angular isn't working if theres some the application.html.erb

Comment: @max is it something to do with multiple declartions of angular apps?

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you looked at the console?

Comment: ways to use **with** turbolinks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797935/using-angularjs-with-turbolinks

Comment: @max - Hey max - I think you deserve the bounty. I suggest posting an answer - and I'll award you the bounty. I can edit it as needed.

Comment: Give it to Mohamed. I don't really need rep...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed your steps and configured angular the same way you did.
I removed turbolinks and this solved the first problem. The second problem was due to wrong usage of the [`ngApp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) directive.

**AngularJS ngApp documentation**

> The ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and
>   is typically placed near the root element of the page

and

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document.

That said. You have `ng-app=""` twice in your code. And since one application only can be bootstrapped, the first `div` containing angular code in your `application.html.erb` would work but the other in `index.html.erb` would not.

The solution to your problem is place `ng-app=""` on your `<body>` or `<html>` tags in your `application.html.erb` according to your needs. (If you want angular to manipulate tags in the `<head>` section like page `<title>` for example just place `ng-app=""` on your `<html>` tag. If not just place it on your body tag.

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HelloRails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body style = "background-color:green" ng-app="">

  This is application.html.erb <br>
  <div>
    <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="home_name"></p>
    <h1>Hello {{home_name}} at home</h1>
  </div>

   <%= link_to "click here to go home", root_path %> <br>


A yeild statement is below: <br>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**Manipulating page title by placing `ngApp` in `<html>`**

```
<html  ng-app="">
<head>
  <title>{{home_name}} | HelloRails</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
...
```

Works like a charm!

[image: After adding ngApp to body tag]

Here are some resources for using Angular with Rails and correctly configure turbolinks with Angular.
[Resource 1](https://www.leighhalliday.com/can-i-use-angular-in-my-rails-app)
[Resource 2](http://asanderson.org/posts/2013/06/23/bootstrapping-angular-rails-part-2.html)