# "Tried to load angular more than once" warning - Only on initial page load

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm getting the `Tried to load angular more than once` warning only when I load the page initially.

Due to this warning, my bindings don't seem to work. But when I reload the page, I don't get the warning and everything seems to bind and work correctly.

**I'm not using any routes or ui-view!** (I've seen the other SO posts and I don't think they apply to my case).

I double checked and made sure that I only have Angular JS referenced once. My usage of Angular JS is really simple at this point.

I have Angular JS referenced in the layout / the master page in this order -

```
jquery
jquery-ujs   // Rails Unobtrusive jQuery Adapter
jquery-ui
angular
foundation  // ZURB Foundation 6
turbolinks  // Rails Turbolinks
```

Here is how my Angular template looks like -

```
<body ng-app="test">
   <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div ng-init="items = <%= items.to_json %>">
         <div ng-repeat="item in items">
           <p ng-bind="item"></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

`items` is a Rails object and I basically hand it off to Angular for the initial load.

Here is what I have in the Javascript in my Layout page -

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
```

Here is what I have in the Javascript for the View / Content page -

```
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile',    function($scope, $http, $compile){ 
   // Some Functions
}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Note:** The `Tried to load angular more than once` warning shows up for every page I visit unless I reload the page and I don't get the warning and the bindings seem to work correctly.

Here is a screenshot, after visiting 4 pages without reloading any of them -

[image]

Once I reload a page, I don't get the warning and the bindings work correctly.

Comment: check `<div ng-repeat="item in <%= items.to_json %>">`

Comment: Apologies! I have a `ng-init` above that line. Edited the code.

Comment: Try to avoid using `ng-init` inside controllers (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) when it's possible to assign values within controller itself (via $scope)

Comment: @OlegMeleshko - Still getting the warning and having the same behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this issue resolved. This is **NOT** an issue with Angular JS (or just Angular JS).

I removed all the Angular JS code and I was still getting the warning. The issue was with **Turbolinks**.

I believe there are 2 solutions.

### Solution 1 - Remove Turbolinks

I removed Turbolinks from my Layout's page's JS reference and restarted the server and everything seemed to work fine.

Here is how my javascript references looks like -

```
jquery
jquery-ujs
jquery-ui
angular
foundation
```

If you're not really using Turbolinks, you might as remove it.

### Solution 2 - Add `data-no-turbolink` attribute

I came across this thread - [Using angularjs with turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797935/using-angularjs-with-turbolinks)

But apparently, the marked answer did't seem to work for me.

As one of the comments pointed out, it works for `angular-1.0.6` and less.

Although, one of the answers suggested to add `data-no-turbolink` attribute to tag where you specify `ng-app`. This worked like a charm.

My version of Angular is `1.4.8`

So, here is how my Angular template looks like now -

```
<body ng-app="test" data-no-turbolink>
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
     <div ng-init="items = <%= items.to_json %>">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <p ng-bind="item"></p>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this html code:

```
<body ng-app="test">
   <div ng-controller="TestController" ng-init="init(<%= items.to_json %>)">
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
         <p ng-bind="item"></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

And in controller:

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {        
   $scope.items = [];
   // ...
   $scope.init = function(items) {
     $scope.items = items;
   }; 
}]);
```

After that please check for missing template files (not loaded correctly). There is a chance that `routerProvider` decided to load default root document after failed attempt to load specified template (`templateUrl` is wrong or not loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Check

1) Does your browser network tab show more than one angular.js reference?

2) Lets see if the issue is due to the code inside.
For that comment the whole code inside ng-controller div.

```
<body ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <!--<div ng-init="items = <%= items.to_json %>">
          <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <p ng-bind="item"></p>
          </div>
  </div>-->
</div>
</body>
```